# rowspan Doesn't work when add the scrollbar

Tags: html, css

without styles table is formatted with rowspan. it can be seen in image one. But when i add scroll bar
by uncommenting styles [that is add scrollbar related styles], rowspan go away.but scroll bar is appeared. this can be seen in image2. I need to enable scroll bar with rowspan.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Scroll</title>
    <style>
        table, tr td,th {
            border: 1px solid red
        }
        /*
        tbody {
            display: block;
            height: 80px;
            overflow: auto;
        }

            thead, tbody tr {
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                table-layout: fixed;
            }

        thead {
            width: calc( 100% - 1em )
        }

        table {
            width: 400px;
        }*/
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div> <table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>phone</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="2">AAAA</td><td>111</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>222</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">AAAA</td>
<td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>CCCCC</td>
            <td>3435656</td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody>
</table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**without scrollbar : *rowspan WORK***

[image: without scrollbar-rowspan]

**with scrollbar : *rowspan DOESN'T WORK***

[image: with scrollbar-rowspan]

Comment: Its because you use `display: table` that will ignore the rowspan

Comment: i deleted display: table . but it doesn't work

Comment: No deleting that will not solve your problem, I also have no idea to fix that, I think that is not possible in this way.